# How to display a windows desktop notification?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a timer in a form, and I would like to send a notification every 10 seconds. My code result is to popup a notification down and right in my screen. However, I wish to get the notification from windows desktop window which is placed in the same point of our screen (close to the hour& date). Here is my code till now:

```
    public int _ticks;

    public NotificationForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _ticks++;           

        if ((_ticks % 10) == 0)
        {
            PopupNotifier popup = new PopupNotifier();
            popup.TitleText = "New";
            popup.ContentText = "10 seconds have passed";
            popup.Popup();
        }
    }
```

[image]
What I really need, is to have a notification from this place(windows native way):

Comment: If the PopupNotifier class allows you to set "Location" like a normal windows form, then you can use PopupNotifier.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - PopupNotifier.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - PopupNotifier.Height);

Comment: What is `PopupNotifier`? Which library is it?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but my issue is not about the location of notification! I wish to displayed the notification in the native windows way(which is placed down and right of our screen)

Comment: @Sinatr Tulpep.NotificationWindow

Comment: As I understood it the notification works correctly. So what is the problem exactly? I can't decipher *"I wish to get the notification from windows desktop window which is placed in the same point of our screen"*. Is your notification covers some other notification? What you would like to have instead?

Comment: *"in the native windows way"* - try to use [NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.showballoontip), perhaps there are other ways (toast notifications of windows 10? some other library?)

Comment: I have posted an image so as to be more specific in my post. ty again for your help!

Comment: So what you really wanted was a windows notification. Try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-desktop?tabs=msix-sparse